# AVPlayerItem: KVO for multiple tracks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to register my AVQueuePlayer items for KVO at the time of initializing. Below, the items in `itemArray` have all been properly created with URLs. After the code the queueList is added to a AVQueuePlayer. The player plays fine, with each item playing in order, but only observers for the first item trigger the response. The `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEnd` works for all items, however.

I'm fairly new to KVO. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        for(AVPlayerItem *i in itemArray)

    {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nextSong)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:i];
        [i addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
        [i addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:0 context:nil];
        [i addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:0 context:nil];

        [queueList addObject:item];

    }

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    AVPlayerItem *thisItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        if ([self.player rate]!=0) {
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:YES];
            NSLog(@"PLAYING");
        }
        else {
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:NO];
            NSLog(@"PAUSED");
                    }
    }
    else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if(thisItem.status==AVPlayerItemStatusFailed)
        {
            NSLog(@"failed");
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:NO];
            [player pause];
        }
    }
    else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
    {
        if(thisItem.playbackBufferEmpty)
        {
            [player pause];
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:NO];
        }
    }
    else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
    {
        if(!thisItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
        {
            [player pause];
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [player play];
            [self setPlayButtonAsPlaying:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I also have a button which triggers this command, which I use to test the state of these properties.**

```
NSLog(player.currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty ? @"Yes" : @"No");
NSLog(player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Specifically, playbackLikelyToKeepUp is false (which I manually cause by disconnecting my wifi). Interestingly, the playBackBufferEmpty is also false.

Comment: Can you post your observeValueForKeyPath implementation?

Comment: Your AVPlayerItem is missing an asterisk (*) in your for loop head:  for(AVPlayerItem i in itemArray) - Is this a typo?

Comment: Yea sorry that was a typo I just cleaned a few things up for the sake of posting it here.

Comment: I actually don't have a problem with it when testing on the device itself so maybe its an emulator issue. Thanks for taking a look though!